# Sending a quote and an attachment by email

Tags: attachment, urlhacking, quote

Is it possible to add a document to the "Email Quote" button from the Quote object?

[image]

Our sales team need to send an intro.pdf with the quote object.

Using URL Hacking, I am only able to add a single doc_id to the email page.
[Adding an attachment to the EmailAuthor page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13339/adding-an-attachment-to-the-emailauthor-page)

Is it possible to add 2 documents ?

How can I add the document by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more than one document, I recommend you look at [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46327/2212) by @Eyescream which refers to blog posts by Jeff Douglass and a Helper Class that creates a map of the pages to be rendered as a single attachment. It's an answer to a question describing a solution someone came up with for doing the type of thing you describe.

For a single document, if you don't want to preview the document, use [getContentAsPDF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm) in a custom button to add it to an email template. If you want to preview the PDF first, see @MichaelWelburn [Blog Post](http://michaelwelburn.com/2013/03/18/sending-visualforce-pages-as-email-attachments-in-salesforce/) on how to do it via a button. You may also want to view @CA_Peterson's answer to [How to download a VF page as PDF and email it from a trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/how-to-download-a-vf-page-as-pdf-and-email-it-from-a-trigger/1395#1395).

Another post that may be of interest would be [too many nested getContent calls?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83275/too-many-nested-getcontent-calls).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I am not interested to view any page as PDF. I have a quote pdf in the quote object. And when sending it, I want to attach (by default if possible) a second attachment.

Comment: Then create a custom button to get to your email template that uses getContentAsPDF as described in the 1st link of 2nd paragraph above. I can't seem to locate sample button code I have for this purpose. From a link on @MichaelWeldon Blog, tips on creating the button: http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html.